# How use tinymce richtext as transparent api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, tinymce

we're using here a textarea in a form which can be switched to a tinymce-richtexteditor. This is a part of a bit more complex system and it works fine. But...

For some reasons the system adds javascriptevents dynamically on selected formelements and I want to use them too, if the field is in RTE-modus and I need the same interface to get the value.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call `tinymce.triggerSave()`.
This writes the tinymce editor content back to the original form field.

Comment: Ok, but thats not only what I need. The textarea-element can have different events registered on and the richtextbox should trigger them as well.

Comment: this won't work. what you call richtextbox is not a box - in fact its a contenteditable iframe. if you want to register events you need to adress the document of that iframe